# Android ripple effect overlapped by imageView / GIF

Tags: android, imageview, ripple

I've got a list item in a recycle view and I want to get the ripple effect all over the element - currently my GIF is overlapping the ripple. I don't know how to fix this, already tried a lot of ways after researching, but nothing worked.

[image: example of the non working ripple effect]

Here is the specific XML file on which basis I build each list item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/selector"
android:clickable="false">

<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
    android:layout_width="84dp"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/a_present_for_you"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_lock_open_blue_24dp"
    android:drawablePadding="16dp">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `FrameLayout`? Wrap those two elements with `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, and set `android:foreground` of this layout with your custom selector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:foreground="@drawable/selector">

<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
android:layout_width="84dp"
android:layout_height="84dp"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
android:paddingRight="1dp"
android:paddingLeft="1dp"
android:background="@drawable/a_present_for_you"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_lock_open_blue_24dp"
android:drawablePadding="16dp">
</TextView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Just tested it, works great! But in the end I went with the way of letting the gif overlapping the ripple, because I realized it looks quite great in the right context.

Answer (score 1):

Just use these following attributes:-

`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`
for simple ripple effect.
For circular ripple effect use 
`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

inside the main root.

Answer (score 0):

The Ripple effect isn't propagating becouse you have two different backgrounds in the same LinearLayout. What you can try to do, is set the ripple effect to the whole LinearLayout.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the problem, but I can't show the gif in a different way. Tried it with `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/a_present_for_you"` instead of `android:background="@drawable/a_present_for_you"` but it still overlapps. What do you exactly mean with setting it to the whole LinearLayout? Thought I've done this by setting `android:background="@drawable/selector"` on top.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#40000000">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </item>
</ripple>`

Comment: try setting `android:clickable="true"` in your LinearLayout